# On the usage of global option "style=..."

Tags: class-options, option-clash

I created a document class and it has a key-val option `style=...` for setting the visual style of it. Now I load my class as follows:

```tex
\documentclass[style=STYLE1]{MyClass}
```

And since this option is global, it passes to every package below, as a result, my own option conflict with other packages' option, and errors happen:

```
LaTeX3: Key '.../options/style' accepts only a fixed set of choices.
```

I know that this problem could be solved by changing my own option's name, for example to `mystyle=...`. But I would like to keep it as `style=...` as it's much easier to remember. Is there any way I can keep this name without any conflict?

Comment: which package clash?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This error is produced by zhnumber, but some other packages such as classicthesis also have this option and may get clashed.

Comment: then complain to the package author of zhnumber, they should either not process class options but only package options with  `\ProcessKeysPackageOptions`, or avoid that unknown values errors. As a workaround you could define the unknown handler for the key. `\keys_define:nn { zhnum / options  } {unknown .code:n ={}}`